# jbpm 6 - task id unique across process instances

Tags: jbpm

The task service API lifecycle methods require a task ID and a user as input. What I would like to know is whether the task ID is unique across process instance ID's or can 2 different processes have the same task ID?

e.g.

process instance id: 1 task id: 25

process instance id: 2 task id: 25

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just like process instance id, task id will also be unique across all the process instances.

Eg. If a process instance with id : 1 has 2 tasks with task id 1 and task id 2, then a new process instance with id : 2 will have task ids 3 and 4.